# $(window).scroll event not triggered in android WebView

Tags: android, jquery, scroll, android-webview, touch-event

In android app I have webView page that use jquery plugin for lazyload. In mobile browser it work fine but not in webView. After debug I find out that even this doesnt trigger alert.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    alert("Scrolled");
}
```

Does there is special way to handle  scroll events in webView?

PS For lazy load i use this plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Hi Alex, Did you find any workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`window.onscroll` works with the WebView. Some things to check:

1. you have placed the WebView in a ScollView and/or set it's height to wrap_contents,
2. the contents of the WebView is too short to scroll,
3. you haven't implemented the WebChromeClient.onJsAlert callback to handle alert. By default the WebView doesn't display a popup.